# how to convert a json output to a string value

Tags: python

i am trying to convert a json output to string value. I have a api output which gives uuid , country and date  . I am storing it as excel and to store it i need to convert uuid , date as string so that the excel will recognize it.

this is my api output

```
 "account_id": "10996fd6-a708-4d70-b65e-50620d8fbbdf",
        "country": "'USA'",
        "end_date": "Fri, 03 Sep 2021 00:00:00 GMT",
        "start_date": "Thu, 03 Sep 2020 00:00:00 GMT"
```

this is my code

```
esult = db.session.execute(text(update_query), {'a':email})
final = [dict(i) for i in result]
excel = json.dumps(final, default=str)
print(excel)
excels = json.load(excel)
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('myfile.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
col = 0

for key in excels:
    row += 1
    worksheet.write(row, col, key)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, excels[key])
    print(workbook)
    workbook.close()
```

but still the uuid is in uuid form
kindly guide

Comment: How about ```worksheet.write(row, col + 1, str(excels[key]))```

Comment: i didnt get you @ yash shah

Comment: With `str(excels[key])` you cast your value to a string.

Comment: *"so that the excel will recognize it"* - what does Excel do instead? Is there an error? Show it.

Comment: Also, if all you ask about is the UUID, and the other fields work, then the other fields are irrelevant to your problem. Remove them from your question and make your question only about the UUID.

Comment: ```excels[key]``` in line ```worksheet.write(row, col + 1, excels[key])``` seems to add data in the format in which data is stored in json. so how about converting the data to str using ```worksheet.write(row, col + 1, str(excels[key]))```

Comment: i did try add str(excels[key]) and.i got str' object has no attribute 'read' error , so.i am trying to take the dictionary list and typecast them  separately which i dont know how to do.